# Как взаимодействовать с окном из другого файла qt

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, label

Не могу разобраться, подключил MainWindows.h Но все равно не работает

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include <someclass.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_action_2_triggered();

    void on_action_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *dil;
    QThread *thread;
//    SomeClass* worker = new SomeClass();

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**someclass.cpp:**

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H
#include <QObject>
#include "mainwindow.h"


class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setFilePath(QString fp) {
    if (file_path!=fp)
       file_path=fp;
}
    explicit SomeClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void func(QString file_path);


private:
  QString file_path;

};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

**someclass.cpp**:

```
#include "someclass.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "mainwindow.h"
SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent):
    QObject{parent},
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) \\Вот тут ошибка
{
    ui->setupUi(this); \\Тут тоже
}
```

**Нужно** просто к примеру изменить текст label **в** основном окне(*mainwindow*) **из** потока **someclass**

Ошибки:

> someclass.cpp:9:12: error: allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::MainWindow'
> mainwindow.h:9:22: note: forward declaration of 'Ui::MainWindow'

> C:\QtTools\TestFirst\someclass.cpp:11: ошибка: use of undeclared identifier 'ui'

Comment: и не должно. ui в одном классе, а вы их зачем-то пытаетесь в другой класс запихать. Самое простое - удалить все что есть и сесть разобраться как оно должно работать

Comment: Используйте для этого сигналы\слоты

Comment: Сигналы слоты? разве можно их использовать в другом потоке?

Comment: Конечно можно. В Qt данный механизм даже безопасен для межпотокового взаимодействия, необходимости в синхронизации нет.